# How to grep for unicode � in a bash script

Tags: linux, grep, scripting, openssl

```
if grep -q "�" out.txt
    then
        echo "working"
    else
        cat out.txt
fi
```

Basically, if the file "out.txt" contains "�" anywhere in the file I would like it to echo "working" AND if the file "out.txt" does NOT contain "�" anywhere in the file then I would like it to cat out.txt

EDIT: So here's what I'm doing. I'm trying to brute force an openssl decrypt.

openssl enc returns 0 on success, non-zero otherwise. Note: you will get false positives because AES/CBC can only determine if "decryption works" based on getting the padding right. So the file decrypts but it will not be the correct password so it will have gibberish in it. A common character in the gibberish is "�". So I want the do loop to keep going if the output contains "�".

Heres my git link https://github.com/Raphaeangelo/OpenSSLCracker
Heres the script

```
while read line
do
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in $1 -pass pass:$line -out out.txt 2>out.txt >/dev/null && printf "==================================================\n"
if grep -q "�" out.txt
    then
        :
    else
        cat out.txt &&
            printf "\n==================================================" &&
            printfn"\npassword is $line\n" &&
            read -p "press return key to continue..." < /dev/tty; 
fi
done < ./password.txt
```

its still showing me output with the � charicter in it

Comment: It looks correct, it should work (btw, I have no font for your unicode character to see, but none of them has any special meaning). `grep` long understands unicode (which makes it much slower, so to search for ascii strings, a `LANG=C grep` is a huge performance improvement).

Comment: I might have to delete this and post another question because I'm sure I'm completely confusing everyone here.

Comment: @Stuart Sloan the title of your question is `How to grep for unicode � in a bash script` is this really what you want? to extract the unicode? please clarify so we can help!

Comment: @Goro I've made the edit to my original post. I hope it makes sense. Please let me know if it doesn't and I will try an clarify.

Comment: @Goro um.... what?

Comment: @StuartSloan You can't delete even your own question after any of its answers has got its first upvote. But, if you really wanted to ask another question, then you can ask also that, nothing forbids it (the site actually likes to get more content), until they are essentially different.

Comment: @Stuart Sloan : could you please edit the question and confirm that the actual involved character in question is the replacement character (rhombus with an interogation point in it, similar to <?>), and it's not a problem with readers' browser's character set unable to view the correct character in the question ?

Comment: I've completed my script! I have a working openssl brute forcing script. Thanks for everyone's help. If you are interested I left my GIT link in the original post.

Comment: Both present answers are extremely misleading. Please read (again) [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474812/265604), I have edited it to explain waht is wrong with both answers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`grep` is the wrong tool for the job.

You see the � [`U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`](https://codepoints.net/U+FFFD) not because it’s literally in the file content, but because you looked at a binary file with a tool that is supposed to handle only text-based input. The standard way to handle invalid input (i.e., random binary data) is to replace everything that is not valid in the current locale (most probably UTF-8) with U+FFFD before it hits the screen.

That means it is very likely that a literal `\xEF\xBF\xBD` (the UTF-8 byte sequence for the U+FFFD character) never occurs in the file. `grep` is completely right in telling you, there is none.

One way to detect whether a file contains some unknown binary is with the `file(1)` command:

```
$ head -c 100 /dev/urandom > rubbish.bin
$ file rubbish.bin
rubbish.bin: data
```

For any unknown file type it will simply say `data`. Try

```
$ file out.txt | grep '^out.txt: data$'
```

to check whether the file really contains any arbitrary binary and thus most likely rubbish.

If you want to make sure that `out.txt` is a UTF-8 encoded text file only, you can alternatively use `iconv`:

```
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 out.txt >/dev/null
```

Comment: You are exactly right! unfortunately, I'm still getting some (less than before) rubbish in the output.

Comment: Possibly `file` detects some other content type for those files. If you 100% always only expect UTF-8 encoded text files, you can check with `iconv`, if a file is valid UTF-8: `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 out.txt >/dev/null`. If `iconv` cannot convert the file due to invalid UTF-8 sequences, it will return with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The file command was right! You helped me solve my issue thanks!

Comment: Of course that grep "is the tool for the job", try `grep -axv '.*' badchars.txt`. That will print any line that contains any invalid **Unicode** Character.

Comment: `iconv -c ...` will omit invalid input characters silently if you don’t care about them. You can omit the output encoding if you want to use the current locale’s encoding or specify something that makes more sense than UTF-16 in your context.

Comment: This is extremely misleading, please read [in my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474812/265604) about what `file` does.

Answer (score 12):

TL;DR:

```
grep -axv '.*' out.txt
```

---

## long answer

Both present answers are extremely misleading and basically wrong.

To test, Get this two files (from a very well regarded developer: Markus Kuhn ):

```
$ wget https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt
$ wget https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt
```

## Demo

The first `UTF-8-demo.txt` is a file designed to show how well UTF-8 is able to present many languages, math, braille and many other useful types of characters. Take a look with a text editor (that understand utf-8) and you will see a lot of examples and **no** `�`.

The test that one answer propose: to limit the character range to `\x00-\x7F` will reject almost everything inside this file.
That is very wrong and **will not remove any `�` as there is none in that file**.

Using the test recommended in that answer will remove `72.5 %` of the file:

```
$ grep -oP "[^\x00-\x7F]" UTF-8-demo.txt | tr -d '\n' | wc -c
10192
$ cat UTF-8-demo.txt | wc -c
14058
```

That is (for most practical purposes) the whole file. A file very well designed to show perfectly valid characters.

## Test

The second file is designed to try several border cases to confirm that utf-8 readers are doing a good job. It contains inside many characters that will cause a '�' to be shown. But the other answer recommendation (the selected one) to use `file` fails grossly with this file. Only removing a zero byte (`\0`) (which technically is valid ASCII) and a `\x7f` byte (DEL - delete) (which is clearly an ASCII character as well) will make **all** the file valid for the `file` command:

```
$ cat UTF-8-test.txt | tr -d '\0\177' > a.txt
$ file a.txt 
a.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with LF, NEL line terminators
```

Not only does `file` fail to detect the **many** incorrect characters, but also fail to detect and report that it is an UTF-8 encoded file.

And yes, `file` is able to detect and report UTF-8 encoded text:

```
$ echo "ééakjfhhjhfakjfhfhaéá" | file -
/dev/stdin: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Also, `file` fails to report as ASCII most of the control characters in the range 1 to 31. It (`file`) reports some ranges as `data`:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%x' {1..6})" | file -
/dev/stdin: data
```

Others as `ASCII text`:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%x' 7 {9..12})" | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

As the printable character range (with newlines):

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%x' {32..126} 10)" | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

But some ranges may cause weird results:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%x' {14..26})" | file -
/dev/stdin: Atari MSA archive data, 4113 sectors per track, starting track: 5141, ending track: 5655
```

The program `file` is not a tool to detect text, but to detect *magic* numbers in executable programs or files.

The ranges `file` detect, and the corresponding type reported I found were:

- One byte values, mostly ascii:

  ```
  {1..6} {14..26} {28..31} 127   :data
  {128..132} {134..159}          :Non-ISO extended-ASCII text
  133                            :ASCII text, with LF, NEL line terminators
  27                             :ASCII text, with escape sequences
  13                             :ASCII text, with CR, LF line terminators
  8                              :ASCII text, with overstriking
  7 {9..12} {32..126}            :ASCII text
  {160..255}                     :ISO-8859 text
  ```
- Utf-8 encoded ranges:

  ```
  {1..6} {14..26} {28..31} 127   :data
  27                             :ASCII text, with escape sequences
  13                             :ASCII text, with CR, LF line terminators
  8                              :ASCII text, with overstriking
  7 {9..12} {32..126}            :ASCII text
  {128..132} {134..159}          :UTF-8 Unicode text
  133                            :UTF-8 Unicode text, with LF, NEL line terminators
  {160..255}                     :UTF-8 Unicode text
  {256..5120}                    :UTF-8 Unicode text
  ```

One possible solution lies below.

---

## Previous Answer.

The Unicode value for the character you are posting is:

```
$ printf '%x\n' "'�"
fffd
```

Yes, that is a [Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FFFD/index.htm). That is a character used to replace any **invalid** Unicode character found in the text. It is a "visual aid", not a real character.  To find and list every full line that contains invalid **UNICODE** characters use:

```
grep -axv '.*' out.txt
```

but if you only want to detect if any character is invalid, use:

```
grep -qaxv '.*' out.txt; echo $?
```

If the result is `1` the file is clean, otherwise will be zero `0`.

---

If what you were asking was: how to find the `�` character, then, use this:

```
➤ a='Basically, if the file "out.txt" contains "�" anywhere in the file I'
➤ echo "$a" | grep -oP $(printf %b \\Ufffd)
�
```

Or if your system process correctly UTF-8 text, simply:

```
➤ echo "$a" | grep -oP '�'
�
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much for `grep -axv '.*' `!! I've struggled with a few bad characters in my text files, and how to fix them in emacs, for a decade or two!!!

Comment: @user232326 This is a very clever trick. However, I have a file with some invalid chars and `grep -axv '.*'` returns nothing, `grep -axv '.+'` returns the whole file. `grep (GNU grep) 3.7 Packaged by Cygwin (3.7-2)`. Why might that be??

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev I believe the important part is its status code. `if grep -axv '.*' {file} >& /dev/null; then echo valid; else echo invalid; fi`

Answer (score 4):

This very early answer was for the original post which was:

> #### How to grep for unicode � in a bash script
>
> ```
> if grep -q "�" out.txt
>     then
>         echo "working"
>     else
>         cat out.txt  fi
> ```
>
> Basically, if the file "out.txt" contains "�" anywhere in the file I would like it to echo "working" AND if the file
>   "out.txt" does NOT contain "�" anywhere in the file then I would like
>   it to cat out.txt

Try

```
grep -oP "[^\x00-\x7F]"
```

with an `if .. then` statement as follows:

```
if grep -oP "[^\x00-\x7F]" file.txt; then
    echo "grep found something ..."
else
    echo "Nothing found!"
fi
```

Explanation:

- `-P`, `--perl-regexp`: PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
- `-o`, `--only-matching`: show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
- `[^\x00-\x7F]` is a regex to match a single non-ASCII character.
- `[[:ascii:]]` - matches a single ASCII char
- `[^[:ascii:]]` - matches a single non-ASCII char

in `bash`

```
LC_COLLATE=C grep -o '[^ -~]' file
```

Comment: This will break (have a false positive) as soon as someone doesn't speak English...

Comment: or if someone tries discussing à la carte, emoji, Pokémon, or anything else not strictly confined to 7bit ASCII. Better look for anything in 00-1F, except 09 0A 0D (tab, linefeed, carriage return).

Comment: This is a very ver bad idea. This will reject **any** valid Unicode char above the ASCII range, just only a little more than a million valid characters. Amazing. Try: `printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%x' {128..131})" | grep -oP "[^\x00-\x7F]"` Just 4 valid Unicode characters that your code reject. :-(

Comment: This is an extremely misleading answer. Please read [in my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474812/265604) why the simplistic approach of limiting only to ASCII fails grossly.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to wrangle this into working by using the tools 'iconv' to perform encoding conversions, and 'xxd' to convert raw binary into hex digits.  It turns the file into a UTF-32 BE (big endian) byte stream, so that the shell can examine the real Unicode character code point without needing to include extra logic.

The example requests just detecting if a single Unicode character exists in the file.  Let's say that the character is `\u1234abcd` (not valid, but this is for an example).

```
# iconv does its best to detect the encoding and convert it to UTF-32 BE
iconv -t utf32be out.txt | \
# xxd turns the raw binary into hex digits and some new lines.
# The '-g 1' attempts to avoid local computer endian-ness by grouping 1
# byte at a time.  It may not be necessary.
xxd -g 1 -R never -ps | \
# 'tr' strips out whitespace generated by 'xxd'.
tr -d '\r\n ' | \
# Loop over each 8 hex digit character.
# This causes the shell to read the input stream
# 8 characters at a time which, if everything above
# went right, is limited to 0-9 and a-f.  LANG=C
# just enforces 1 byte at a time.
while IFS='' LANG=C read -r -d '' -n 8 char ; do
  if [ "${char}" = "1234abcd" ] ; then
    echo "working"
    # No need to scan any other character.  Exit early.
    break
  fi
done
```

Unlike the main question, the answer above does not perform the followup of, if not found, run `cat out.txt`.  That would require passing the found state outside the inner execution.  My usual go-to involves flagging with the existence of a file.  Some enterprising individual may uncover a way to use sub-processes and exit codes to work more like grep.

```
# Create the marker file.
marker="$( mktemp )"

iconv -t utf32be out.txt | \
xxd -g 1 -R never -ps | \
tr -d '\r\n ' | \
while IFS='' LANG=C read -r -d '' -n 8 char ; do
  if [ "${char}" = "1234abcd" ] ; then
    echo "working"
    # Mark that it was found by removing the temporary file.
    rm "${marker}"
    break
  fi
done

# If the marker file exists, then it wasn't found in the loop.
if [ -f "${marker}" ] ; then
  rm "${marker}"
  cat out.txt
fi
```

You can use 'od' or 'hexdump' instead of 'xxd', if you're very very careful about only generating the hex digits and avoiding endian-ness conversions.

The 'xxd' has the advantage of providing a reverse capability to go back into raw data.  The same thing can be done with `echo -e "\xAf"' style output, but that requires spawning a new echo process for every parsed character.

I put this into [a gist](https://gist.github.com/groboclown/f3be4f70de82f6bee3a61553b61d7ff1) to show it in a larger example, including how to reassemble the output into a UTF encoded stream.